# Calculate the weighted minutes between two dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date, time, duration

How to calculate the weighted minutes between two dates using Excel?

The minutes have to be divided like in below table.

For instance, if start date is Friday at 23:00 and end date Saturday at 00:10 the result should be:

```
60 minutes from Friday 23:00 to Saturday 00:00
10/8 = 1.25 minutes from Saturday 00:00 to Saturday 00:10
Total: 61.25 minutes
```

[image: division matrix]

Comment: For Saturday.. [ 00:00-07:00 ] in the table is 8.. but in your post. is 10 is divided by 2.. why?

Comment: Thank you for feedback. The first example was wrong. It's corrected now. Thanks!

Comment: How about the input time.. is your "Friday at 23:00" & "Saturday at 00:10" data is date + time in one cell or time is separated?

Comment: Data is date + time in same cell, recognised by Excel as date time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For convinience, extend your divisor list table to :

```
Interval        1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0700 - 0000     1   1   1   1   1   2   5
0000 -0700      4   4   4   4   4   8   16
```

Assuming you built the table in A1:H3 cells, put on these labels :

```
A6 ---> start time
A7 ---> end time
C5 ---> day
D5 ---> total minutes
E5 ---> before 0700 (2) or after (1)
F5 ---> devide by
G5 ---> calc
H8 ---> Sum
```

where B6 is you start time value, and B7 is you end time value.

put in these formula (and observe how it works) :

```
C6 ---> =WEEKDAY(B6,2)
D6 ---> =24*60-HOUR(B6)*60-MINUTE(B6)
E6 ---> =IF(TIME(HOUR(B6),MINUTE(B6),SECOND(B6))>TIME(7,0,0),1,2)
F6 ---> =INDEX($B$2:$H$3,E6,MATCH(C6,$B$1:$H$1,0))
G6 ---> =D6/F6
```

and drag it to C7:G7 . Except for

```
D7 ---> =(HOUR(B7))*60+MINUTE(B7)
G8 ---> =SUM(G6:G7)
```

Does it works? Do share if you get stuck in understanding the formulas.

---

***Edit (part 2, based on comment +part 3 after recreate new sample file)***

Do take time to understand the sequence/excelFunction used...  I had embedded the formula/typing sequence as part of the "strategy" that I would like to share..

Assuming the start date/time is in A13 and the end is in B13, put on these labels :

```
A12  ---->  start time
B12  ---->  end time
C12  ---->  dayNo
D12  ---->  dateEachDay
E12  ---->  before 7
F12  ---->  after 7
G12  ---->  divisor before 7
H12  ---->  divisor after 7
I12  ---->  sub total
A15  ---->  dateForEquation
C18  ---->  last day :
K19  ---->  Sum
```

and this value :

C13  ---->  1

First batch formulas (get date only data from date/time data) :

```
A16  ---->  =DATE(YEAR(A13),MONTH(A13),DAY(A13))
B16  ---->  =DATE(YEAR(B13),MONTH(B13),DAY(B13))

C13  ---->  1
D13  ---->  =A16
D18  ---->  =B16
```

2nd batch part 1 (1st day n last day minute count) :

```
E13  ---->  =IF(TIME(HOUR(A13),MINUTE(A13),SECOND(A13))<TIME(7,0,0),7*60-HOUR(A13)*60-MINUTE(A13),0)
F13  ---->  =IF(TIME(HOUR(A13),MINUTE(A13),SECOND(A13))>=TIME(7,0,0),24*60-HOUR(A13)*60-MINUTE(A13),24*60-7*60)
E18  ---->  =IF(TIME(HOUR(B13),MINUTE(B13),SECOND(B13))<TIME(7,0,0),HOUR(B13)*60-MINUTE(B13),7*60)
F18 ---->  =IF(TIME(HOUR(B13),MINUTE(B13),SECOND(B13))>TIME(7,0,0),HOUR(B13)*60+MINUTE(B13)-420,0)
```

2nd batch part 2 (the in-between-full-days minute count), need to be drag until F17 :

```
C14  ---->  =IF(D14="",0,7*60)
D14  ---->  =IF(D14="",0,17*60)
E14  ---->  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$H$3,MATCH(WEEKDAY($D14,2),$B$1:$H$1,0)),1)
F14  ---->  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$H$2,MATCH(WEEKDAY($D14,2),$B$1:$H$1,0)),1)
```

3rd batch, (use index() n match() to get respective divisor + calc) drag until J18 :

```
G13  ---->  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$H$3,MATCH(WEEKDAY($D13,2),$B$1:$H$1,0)),1)
H13  ---->  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$H$2,MATCH(WEEKDAY($D13,2),$B$1:$H$1,0)),1)
I13  ---->  =E13/G13
J13  ---->  =F13/H13
```

Lastly..

```
J19  ---->  =SUM(I13:J18)
```

Just buzz if you stuck somewhere in understanding it.. Please help me to double check (hand calculation?) it though..  ( :

---

***Edit (part 3, based on "27-02-2018 21:20:00 at the end time (B13)" case)***

Since it is on the same day.. Use A21 as the start date/time and B21 as the end date/time ..

at A22, Extract the date using `=DATE(YEAR(A21),MONTH(A21),DAY(A21))` ..

at B22, Get the weekday of the date using `WEEKDAY(A22,2)`...

Then at C22 get the minutes before 0700 hrs using `=IF(TIME(HOUR(A21),MINUTE(A21),SECOND(A21))>TIME(7,0,0),0,IF(TIME(HOUR(B21),MINUTE(B21),SECOND(B21))>TIME(7,0,0),7*60-(HOUR(A21)*60+MINUTE(A21)),HOUR(B21)*60+MINUTE(B21))-(HOUR(A21)*60+MINUTE(A21)))`

at D22 get the minutes after 0700 hrs using `=IF(TIME(HOUR(B21),MINUTE(B21),SECOND(B21))<TIME(7,0,0),HOUR(B21)*60+MINUTE(B21)-7*60,HOUR(B21)*60+MINUTE(B21)-(HOUR(A21)*60+MINUTE(A21)))`

using [index/match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match) function, and the weekday defined at B22, 'load' the divisor at E22 & F22 using `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$H$3,MATCH(WEEKDAY($A22,2),$B$1:$H$1,0)),1)` & `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$H$2,MATCH(WEEKDAY($A22,2),$B$1:$H$1,0)),1)` .

and divide the minute to its divisor, using `=C22/E22` & `=D22/F22` at G22 & H22 .

finally get the sum using `=SUM(G22:H22)` @ H3

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried and manage to fill the Excel accordingly to your answer. But in my case seems to not working. What is working is the mapping to divisor list table.

Comment: For instance could we pick a example like: start Tue 27-02-18 18:20 and end: Thu 01-03-18 17:04. If I calculate manually I obtain 2804 normal minutes and 1409 minutes according to division table.

Comment: You'll need to modify it to 'cover' the days in between.. Since you now can see how we can obtain the 'divisor' you'll just need to add the 'full day' minute calculation to the sum @ G8 || Update the post with your tries (screenshot/sample file).. share where exactly you get stuck we'll proceed from there..

Comment: "But in my case seems to not working" <-- my answer post (table `A6:G8`) are meant to fit with your example inputs.. Which have a time gap of less than half day. Since your real case is different, may I know what is the maximum time difference (between the start date/time and the end/time) are we are looking at? is "Tue 27-02-18 18:20 to  Thu 01-03-18 17:04" the maximum time difference?

Comment: Thank you for continuous input. I appreciate it. As difference: would be 5 days, meaning 24x60x5 minutes. Best regards!

Comment: If you don't mind.. you may accept the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It'll remove this question from SO 'unanswered' list. || Alternatively if the example doesn't work for you.. please share the details here. ( :

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry, unfortunately this week I cannot test. I will post my feedback next week. All the best!

Comment: Please do you mind if I would ask you to share the file you worked on? Thank you. Have a nice week!

Comment: To be honest.. I had deleted my previous file.. it works well then.. So I'd recreated [this file](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EZ1Ozg3JoO1NsW5hvHYfziQBQwA1AhCue0WLT5MJNsDVfQ?e=UhXjEz) + made some correction to cover this version.. (you can check my ans edit.. )

Comment: Thank you so much. I filled the file with start 27-02-2018 18:20:00 and end 01-03-18 17:04 and I obtained 1434 minutes. But when I do the calculation manually I obtain 2174 minutes. I do not get it why is so big difference. Best regards!

Comment: Make sure the date+time is properly formatted in excel's time + data format @ cell A13 & B13. Just to check..  My manual calculations is .. || Say,   total = day1 + day2 + day3 || Where,   day1  = 0 + [1820hrs to 2400hrs]/4 = 0 + 340/4 = 85 || day2 = [0001hrs to 0700hrs]/1 + [0701hrs to 2400 hrs]/4 = 420/1 + 1020/4= 675 || day3 = [0001hrs to 0700hrs]/1 + [0701hrs to 1704 hrs]/4 = 420/1 + 1016/4 = 674 || So, my calc is..  total = 85 + 675 + 674 = 1434  .. May I know your manual calculation details.. (should I missed something/numbers/weight)

Comment: My manual calculation is:day1 27-02-2018 18:20:00 to 28-02-2018 00:00 = 340 mins without division because we are here between Monday-Friday 07:00-24:00.

Comment: Next days: Day 2 night: 28-02-2018 00:00 - 28-02-2018 07:00 = 420/4 = 105 mins. Day 2 day: 28-02-2018 07:00 - 01-03-2018 00:00 = 1020. Day 3 night: 01-03-2018 00:00 - 01-03-2018 07:00 = 420/4 = 105 mins. Day 3 day: 01-03-2018 07:00 - 01-03-2018 17:04 = 604. Total: 340 + 105 + 1020 + 105 + 604 = 2174 mins like I posted before. If you can, let's use this one to fill the excel file you shared. Or if you see something to be changed, please share your thoughts. Thank you so much!

Comment: you are correct.. I get the minutes wrong @ F18 & get the table the other way around the clock.. @ G13:H18 || here's the [new version](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EXIdlYoMYVdMu9m3Kt7nDqcBqCgGnX-rnksqD49pjPN-LQ?e=fNIfIE) .

Comment: Thank you for revision. I saw that on the example is working. But I tried with 27-02-2018  21:20:00 at the end time (B13) and seems to not be good. The result in this case is 5242.5. So I think we should change something, but I don't get it. Could you please help further? Big thanks!

Comment: I designed the excel only for the case with day change... As mentioned before (in my comment).. the designed files "are meant to fit with your example inputs.. ".. and this same day difference are not in the your previous example.. or question post...  || Since you have quite a good gasp of what you need... I really wanted to help you to understand the formula + applying it to your needs. || May I know which part of the formula that you didn't get or stuck at?

Comment: I try to break it down here.. 1.  refer to J13 : (from the formula), it is a result division of 2 numbers ( F13 & H13 ). the 1st number is the minute and 2nd is the divisor.  So we need to get the minutes + 'load' the right divisor from A1:H3 table. || 2. at H13.. (the divisor) : we use `INDEX($B$2:$H$2,MATCH(WEEKDAY($D13,2),$B$1:$H$1,0))` . Read up on [index/match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/) function + `weekday()` function ... It can be seen that the divisor are chosen from B2:H2 [0700hrs - 0000hrs] depending on the weekday of the date specified in D13.

Comment: For the "27-02-2018 21:20:00 at the end time (B13)" case, you may refer my edit. It is specifically for same day start+end, date.

Comment: does it solves? please share if you had solved it by another way.. btw.. you may ask which part of the formula that you didn't get so that we can assist in helping build one. /(^_^)